# Paypal Website Payments Pro - Current Exchange Rates?

Tags: php, paypal

I am just getting started creating a payment form using Website Payments Pro.  I will have customers from all over the world.  Does Paypal have an option for dynamically calculating real-time exchange rates for transactions?  If I post all transactions in USD, does this conversion happen automatically on Paypal's end?  Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buyers are charged in the currency you specify in the DoDirectPayment call (part of Website Payments Pro). The conversion then takes place on their card (or PayPal account, if you're using Express Checkout as well).
Website Payments Pro does not offer an API to calculate exchange rates unfortunately.